# How to embed an Excel spreadsheet into a Word Document programmatically using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel VBA script that pulls data from a couple of files and builds a table in a certain format that suits the business need. I build the table in a hidden worksheet within my main Excel file and all works as intended.

However, I need to insert that table into a Word file. I know how to make a table, but I wanted to try to do an embedded Excel file instead because that way all of the formatting transfers.

I have created an accompanying Word file with a placeholder embedded Excel object. I gave the object (or "shape") a name in the Selection Pane. It's called InvoiceXLS.

I can get as far as opening the Word document and I know how to change basic OLEShapes / objects such as just changing text in named text boxes, but I can't figure out how to get a usable reference to the embedded sheet so that I can call Excel VBA commands on it, and basically replace it with the table I generated earlier in the script.

So far, this is how I open the link to the Word file:

```
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wApp.Visible = True

Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(filename:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\TestAccount.docx")

With wDoc
    .Shapes("InvoiceXLS").OLEFormat.Edit ' ???
    ' How do I get a Worksheet object that I can work with??
    ' Or, just paste in a whole table over top?
End With
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: tthis is from a recorded macro  .... filename was added after recording (intellisense showed filename argument) ... `Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="Excel.Sheet.12", FileName:="abc123.xlsm", LinkToFile:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False`

Comment: I'm trying to access an Excel component/shape/object (whatever it's called) in a Word document from the VBA code within an Excel sheet. I appreciate your answer, but I don't see how it fits. Also, how did you get it to record? When I tried to manipulate an embedded sheet while recording it literally recorded nothing.

Comment: the recording was done in word of _insert table .... excel spreadsheet_. then in vba editor, go to the recorded macro and place the cursor right after `AddOLEObject`, or right after any of the commas.  then press space bar. that brings up _intellisense_ help tooltip